# Push an array in to another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
$profile_typeid [] = custom_profile(
    0 => "44258",
    1 => "44259",
);
```

and another array `$meta_data[]`, I want to push this array `$profile_typeid []`. Before that it should check in  `$meta_data[]` whether it contains  `$profile_typeid []` or not. If not then add other wise it should overwrite.

How can I get the things in PHP

I tried like:

```
   if(!in_array($meta_data,$profile_typeid,true)){
        array_push($meta_data, $profile_typeid);
 }
```

I have var_dump for two arrays like

`array
  'custom_profile_type' => 
    array
      0 => string '39242' (length=5)

null`

Comment: are u got any error?

Comment: `$arr[] = something` is equal to `array_push($arr, something)`. And it works for array. And I can't see anything bad, what error do you get? or what is your current output and desired output?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or did you just notice that the array isn't pushed into the other array? If so? Inject your code with var_dumps (before the if, after the if) and see what's in there.

Comment: remove last comma from `$profile_typeid` array

Comment: The array is coming empty.

Comment: `in_array` — Checks if a **value** exists in an array...

Comment: how are you declaring the variables? what is the var_dump() of both variables displaying?

Comment: yes but i want to check an array exist inside an array or not. The condition satisfies but its not pushing.

Comment: @wayzz i have edited the question just check

Comment: I think you have in_array wrong. Correct syntax in_array(needle, haystack). You are checking in_array(haystack, needle) <- wrong.

Comment: @wayzz Okay....but how can i add the array to the other array

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
in_array($meta_data,$profile_typeid, true)
```

to

```
in_array($profile_typeid,$meta_data)
```

In your syntax you are searching for the haystack in the needle. (so to speak)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

**Update:**

To add in array use array_push.

```
if(!in_array($profile_typeid,$meta_data)){
    array_push($meta_data, $profile_typeid);

 }
else{
    $meta_data['custom_profile_type'] = $profile_typeid;
}
```

Remove the `strict` clause. I do not think it is needed in this context.
This should work.

Comment: Okay i will do this but how can i add the array in to the array.

Comment: I think this should do. Make sure the the variable you are accessing in the array has the correct name in the brackets.

Comment: what is not working? The adding to the array or the overwriting?

Comment: what do you get when you var_dump[] $profile_typeid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67203/discussion-between-wayzz-and-ria-dev).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using below given code ...

```
$profile_typeid = array(
0 => "44258",
1 => "44259",
);

$meta_data = array(
0 => "34567",
1 => "67890",
2 => "44258"
);

foreach($profile_typeid as $pro_type){
   if(!in_array($pro_type,$meta_data)){
      array_push($meta_data, $pro_type);
   }
}
print_r($meta_data);
```

The `in_array(array(), $array, true); // false` you are using which is totally wrong please check the manual for more details http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Good luck with that ..